# Searching the edit history for occurrences of a case-sensitive keyword

Tags: support, edits, search, data-explorer, revisions-list

I wish to search my edit history ("revisions" tab in user profile) for occurrences of a particular keyword. Is it possible to get a list of all such revisions, possibly through SEDE? And can the search be case sensitive?

I went through the SEDE tutorial, and the front page as well, but I didn't find any related table parameters. All I found was these minutely related parameters:

```
SuggestedEdits
Id
int
PostId
int
CreationDate
datetime
ApprovalDate
datetime... (too long)
```

and nothing actually pertaining to "revisions".

Comment: The data should be in the PostHistory table (at least for approved edits). I'm on my cellphone right now and don't really have time to write an example query, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Ps. You do know about [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), right?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Oh, that's a good bookmark-able link. Didn't know about it before. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/818478/revisions-by-user-and-keyword) does what you're looking for. It finds [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22729420/revisions) and [one of your own posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18556896/revisions) when you look for [your user ID and the keyword 'android'](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/818478/revisions-by-user-and-keyword?Keyword=android&UserId=2675672).

Because the query uses `LIKE`, it cannot be case-sensitive.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT 'site://posts/' + CAST(h.PostId AS NVARCHAR) + '/revisions',
  h.Text
  FROM PostHistory AS h
  WHERE h.UserId = ##UserId:int##
    AND h.PostHistoryTypeId = 5 -- Edit Body
    AND h.Text LIKE '%' + ##Keyword:string## + '%'
```

Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do case-sensitive search like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1831105/2675672)? Also, can the query search for full words only? (i.e. the query `"abc"` should match `"abc"` and `"abc def"` but not `"abcd"`) ([somewhat related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6283767/2675672)) Thanks!

Comment: Case-sensitive doesn't work (LIKE doesn't work *like* that). For full words, you could try adding a space before and after the keyword. Feel free to [fork](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/818478) the query if you want to experiment.

Comment: "Case-sensitive doesn't work" Ah, sad, that was important for me. I'll leave the question open in case someone else comes along with another method. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: It does seem that collate does work on a LIKE https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/975140/revisions-by-user-and-keyword?Keyword=Android&UserId=2675672 not sure why you assume it can not. Or am I mis-interpreting the requirement?

Comment: also with `h.Text LIKE '%[^a-z]' + ##Keyword:string## + '[^a-z]%'` you could detect word boundaries

Comment: @rene the only thing you're misinterpreting is my SQL skills. I always forget about collation...